# How can I set the maximum repository size and maximum file size for a GitLab repository on a self-hosted GitLab CE instance?

Tags: git, gitlab

I recently deployed GitLab CE onto a server at home.

Is it possible to set the maximum repository size and maximum file size?

I want to set these for security reasons, and to prevent other people from accidentally uploading large amounts of data to the server.

Comment: You should be able to do that. Do you have access to [these settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html)?

Comment: @harrymc In theory yes, as I am the administrator. However I can't find anything about maximum size under Project > Settings > General > "Naming, Visibility"

Comment: There are [three settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/settings/account_and_limit_settings.html#repository-size-limit) - are they all missing?

Comment: @harrymc Yes - I can see the settings for Enable/Disable LFS, but nothing else ?